# Imprimir todas as páginas da paginação no DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables

Olá, 
Tenho um sistema no qual, em uma de suas páginas, exibo os dados que vem de uma tabela do banco de dados. Sendo que para fazer essa exibição utilizo o plugin Datatables.

O problema é que quando eu tento imprimir (através do botão criado pelo próprio DataTables) ou tento exportar por PDF ou Excel, só é impressa a página atual (que estou). Gostaria que imprimisse todas as páginas que estão disponíveis na paginação.

Vocês sabem se isso é possível ?

**Segue abaixo o código utilizado no DataTables:**

```js
$('#resultado-relatorios-divisao-empresas-por-responsavel').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
    //botão para salvar em pdf
    {
      extend: 'pdfHtml5',
      text: 'Salvar em PDF',
      orientation: 'landscape',
      exportOptions: {
        modifier: {
          page: 'current'
        }
      }
    },
    //botão para salvar em excel
    {
      extend: 'excelHtml5',
      text: 'Gerar Excel',
      orientation: 'landscape',
      exportOptions: {
        modifier: {
          page: 'current'
        }
      }
    },
    //botão para imprimir
    {
      extend: 'print',
      text: 'Imprimir',
      orientation: 'landscape',
      exportOptions: {
        modifier: {
          page: 'current'
        }
      }
    }
  ],

  paging: true,
  scrollX: true,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  scrollY: "400px",

  "language": {
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrando _MENU_ registros por página",
    "zeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado com estes parâmetros de pesquisa",
    "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
    "infoEmpty": "Nenhum registro disponível",
    "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros no total)",
    "search": "Pesquisar:",
    "paginate": {
      "first": "Primeiro",
      "last": "Último",
      "next": "Próximo",
      "previous": "Anterior"
    },
  },

  "language": {
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrando _MENU_ registros por página",
    "zeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado com estes parâmetros de pesquisa",
    "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
    "infoEmpty": "Nenhum registro disponível",
    "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros no total)",
    "search": "Pesquisar:",
    "paginate": {
      "first": "Primeiro",
      "last": "Último",
      "next": "Próximo",
      "previous": "Anterior"
    },
  },

  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": {
    "url": "../banco/banco-vision/pagina-relatorios-divisao-empresas-por-responsavel/php-arquivos-disponiveis.php",
    "type": "POST",
    "data": function(item) {

      item.empresa_origem = $('#empresa_origem_relatorio').val();
      item.departamento = $('#departamento_relatorio').val();
      item.responsavel = $('#responsavel_relatorio').val();
      item.cod = $('#cod_relatorio').val();
      item.empresa = $('#empresa_relatorio').val();
      //item.atividade = $('#atividade_relatorio').val();

    }
  },

});
```

**Segue abaixo a imagem do sistema:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Outra coisa é que quando coloco esses botões abaixo (marcado em vermelho):**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**... Automaticamente ele retira esse botão abaixo (marcado em vermelho):**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Poderiam me ajudar ?**

Answer (score 1):

Você pode selecionar a exibição de todos os itens, realizar a impressão (ou geração do PDF) e selecionar de volta a paginação anterior.

Para selecionar a exibição de todos, você deve primeiramente ter esta opção disponível em pageLength.

```
$('#resultado-relatorios-divisao-empresas-por-responsavel').DataTable({
    pageLength: -1,
    lengthMenu: [[-1], ["Todos"]],
    // outras opções que você tenha....
});


// ... suas funções


// Execute a função abaixo para exibir todos os itens sem paginação
$('.dataTables_length select').val('-1');

ImprimirOuGerarPDF();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#suaTabela").DataTable({
  dom: "Bfrtip",
  lengthMenu: [
    [05, 10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
    ["5", "10", "25", "50", "100", "Todos"],
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
      extend: "print",
      text: "Imprimir",
      autoPrint: true,
    },
    {
      extend: "pageLength",
      text: "Exibir",
    },
  ],
});
```

Esse código adiciona botões e paginação, permitindo ao usuário selecionar a quantidade que deseja imprimir

Comment: Por favor, forneça detalhes adicionais em sua resposta. Como está escrita atualmente, é difícil entender sua solução.